# Attempting to write a livesearch script

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, search

I am attempting a bit of ajax for the first time. I'm trying to write a live search where on every character entered a search of a MySQL database is run.

This is my code so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getStates(value){
            $.post(
                    "getstates.php",
                    {partialState:value},
                    function(data){
                        $("#results").html(data);
                    });
        }
    </script>


</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" name="input" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)" /><br />
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

getStates.php

```
//test the connection
try{
    //connect to the database
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=livesearch","root", "usbw");

//if there is an error catch it here
} catch( PDOException $e ) {
    //display the error
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


$partialState = $_POST['partialState'];     
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT state_name FROM tbl_state WHERE state_name LIKE '%$partialSate%'");      
$query->execute();      
$result = $query->fetchAll();

foreach($result AS $state){

    echo '<div>'.$state['state_name'].'</div>';
}
```

The mySQL database is constructed correctly using the correct table names etc.

Why is it not returning the resulting states from the database?

Comment: Does the error console of your browser provide any errors? How is the output if you request "getStates.php" directly in your browser and provide the needed POST parameter?

Comment: How do i bring up the error console in chrome?

Comment: You have included the jquery lib haven't you?, also your not using prepared query's right..

Comment: yeah I link to the jquery library, Im using PDO to connect to database!?

Comment: try and do an `alert(data);` after the line: `function(data){` so we can see what's going on. also; in chrome, right click anywhere on the webpage and select inspect element, so you can see if any errors exists or occur during the time the code is run

Comment: Have you tried dumping the sql in `$query` and running it against your database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have made a typo in your query:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT state_name 
                        FROM tbl_state 
                        WHERE state_name 
                        LIKE '%$partialSate%'");
                                       ^^^^Missing t
```

Should be

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT state_name 
                        FROM tbl_state 
                        WHERE state_name 
                        LIKE '%$partialState%'");
```

But you should also use prepared query's correctly:
**Fixed code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['partialState'])){

    //test the connection
    try{
        //connect to the database
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=livesearch","root", "usbw");
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        //if there is an error catch it here
    } catch( PDOException $e ) {
        //display the error
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT state_name
                            FROM tbl_state
                            WHERE state_name
                            LIKE :like");

    $query->execute(array(':like'=>'%'.$_POST['partialState'].'%'));

    $result = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach($result AS $state){
        echo '<div>'.$state['state_name'].'</div>';
    }
    die();
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function getStates(value){
        $.post("index.php", { "partialState":value },
        function(data){
            $("#results").html(data);
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" name="input" onkeyup="getStates(this.value)" /><br />
<div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks lawrence, for some reason Jquery isn't working I'm linking to the jquery at top of the page `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`.

Comment: Its tested and it should work. Note I change `$.post("index.php",` for test, you may need to change it back to `$.post("getstates.php",`.

Comment: Lawrence I included my code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uB5SB/ the `getstate.php` just has basic text nothing else. Why could this not be working?